# Problems running Task in VSCODE to build with g++

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to build my first C++ program in VSCODE. I configured a task to use g++ as shown below.  When I choose Terminal-> Run Task... -> "C/C==:g++.exe build active file" I get the following error:

> Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe build active file
>
> Starting build...
>
> D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\dev\C++\vscode_helloworld_v2\helloworld.cpp -o D:\dev\C++\vscode_helloworld_v2\helloworld.exe
>
> The system cannot find
> the path specified.
>
> Build finished with error(s).
>
> - The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
> - Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Here is the tasks.json:

```
    {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "cppbuild",
                "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
                "command": "D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
                "args": [
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": "build",
                "detail": "compiler: D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
            }
        ]
    }
```

If I run the build command in a cmd window or pwsh everything works fine

Comment: Does `D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` exist? Does `D:\dev\C++\vscode_helloworld_v2\helloworld.cpp` exist?

Comment: Yes, If I run the following in a cmd window outside of vscode it works and produces a helloworld.exe "D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\dev\C++\vscode_helloworld_v2\helloworld.cpp -o D:\dev\C++\vscode_helloworld_v2\helloworld.exe"

Comment: I don't know.  It is showing the error message in a terminal window.  What do I check?

Comment: the only path not certainly known by VSC is the path to `g++`, the file variables are based on the file in the editor, try to only add the argument `--version` to find if the `g++` path is correct, because you have set `cwd` you don't need to use full paths

Comment: g++ --version does not display the path.  It only displays the version number. g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: where do I claim g++ returns a path? If the path to g++ is working you have to find the path the error is complaining about, do you have the hello.exe still running?

Comment: When I type g++.exe in the terminal window it is okay but it still does not build when I select "Run Tasks..." from the terminal menu in VSCODE